# C++ Query/ Trying to streamline a condition on an if statement

Tags: c++

I am trying to find a different way to streamline and have a shorter condition that complies with what I need.

```
`if(pagoInicial ==200 or pagoInicial ==300 or pagoInicial ==400 or pagoInicial ==500 or pagoInicial ==600 or pagoInicial ==700 or pagoInicial ==800 or pagoInicial ==200 ){
            cout<<"Maquina Dispensadora 'El Puente'"<<"\n";
            cout<<"1 Papas Fritas         $1200"<<"\n";
            cout<<"2 Sandwich Combinado   $2500"<<"\n";
            cout<<"3 Pescadito            $1800"<<"\n";
            cout<<"4 Empanada             $1700"<<"\n";
            cout<<"5 Arepa                $2000"<<"\n";
            cout<<"6 Gaseosa              $1600"<<"\n";
            cout<<"7 Vaso de Té           $1000"<<"\n";
            cout<<"8 Dulce                 $200"<<"\n"; 
            cout<<"9 Salir"<<"\n";
            cout<<"Digite su opcion"<<"\n";
            cin>>opcion;
    }
```

So, As you can see on my code, the condition of "if" is (pagoInicial == 200 or pagoInicial == 300) but, I'm looking to see a better way to do it

To have a better and readable condition on the if statement

Comment: without seeing more details (for example what other values are ther for pagoInical) its hard to suggest anything else. Sometimes you just have to type the code. I mean you can do fancy things, but it will make the code unclear. Of course 'or' does not exist in c++, you mean ||

Comment: Why not `if (pangoInclinical >= 200 && pangoInclinical <= 800 && pangoInclinical % 100 == 0)`?

Comment: @pm100 `or` [does too exist](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) in C++.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik TIL - ty, coding c++ since Zorland first compiler and still finding new things